# Angular Form Resetting with Ajax Callbacks

Tags: ajax, angularjs, callback, coffeescript, scope

I have a basic form with an Angular `$save` action run on submit:

```
app.controller 'MyThingCtrl', ($scope, MyThing) ->
    this.addThing = ->
      new MyThing(this.thing).$save(
        (data) ->
          console.log 'New Thing Saved'
          $scope.things.push data
          this.thing = {}
        ,(err) ->
          console.log 'Error: ' + err
        )
```

The expectation is that the form for `this.thing` will be reset on success, but it isn't, as the `this` no longer refers to what it did before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the scope of `this` is changed inside the callback, the variable `thing` is available via the `$scope` variable provided by Angular:

```
app.controller 'MyThingCtrl', ($scope, MyThing) ->
    this.addThing = ->
      new MyThing(this.thing).$save(
        (data) ->
          console.log 'New Thing Saved'
          $scope.things.push data
          $scope.thing = {}
        ,(err) ->
          console.log 'Error: ' + err
        )
```