# Angular Form Reset on Successful Submission

Tags: angular

Hoping for someone familiar with Angular to please take a quick look at my syntax.

form.component.html:

`(click)="onSubmit(ruleForm)"`

rule.component.ts:

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
this.dataRulesService.createRuleRequest(this.rule, form, this.newRule);
}

newRule(form: NgForm) {
this.rule = {
  //model is reset
};
form ? form.reset() : null;
}
```

rule.service.ts:

```
  public createRuleRequest(rule: Rule, form: NgForm, newRule: (form: NgForm) 
=> any) {
//logic
this._postCreateRuleRequest(rule, form, newRule);
}

private _postCreateRuleRequest(rule: Rule, form: NgForm, newRule: (form: 
NgForm) => any) {
this.http.post(`${environment.API_URL}rules/create`, 
 rule).subscribe((response: any) => {
  //success logic
  });
  newRule(form);
 }, () => {
 //failure logic
  });
});
}
```

I'm trying to reset the form and the rule model on successful submission only (but keep form state on failure). Fairly new to Angular. I tried to pass the NgForm object itself down and pass the newRule function down to the service.

This is working for a "Clear Form" button I have on the page - but in much simpler way.

When passing newRule down to rule.service, I get an error:

```
vendor.bundle.js:54437 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'rule' of 
undefined
at webpackJsonp../src/app/components/data-rules/data- 
rules.component.ts.DataRulesComponent.newRule
```

I assume this is a reference to this.rule in the newRule function, which works fine when called from within the rule.component but can't find "this.rule" when called from the service.

I should include that rule is being declared publicly:

rule.component.ts:

```
public rule: Rule;
```

Any guidance on this syntax would be appreciated.

Update: Add data-rules.component per request

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataRulesService } from './data-rules.service';
import { Rule }    from './rule';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'app-data-rules',
templateUrl: './data-rules.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./data-rules.component.scss']
})
export class DataRulesComponent implements OnInit {

public rule: Rule;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dataRulesService: 
DataRulesService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.newRule(null);
}

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
this.dataRulesService.createRuleRequest(this.rule, form, this.newRule);
}

newRule(form: NgForm) {
this.rule = {
ruleName: '',
sqlQuery: '',
description: '',
frequency: '',
emailAddressList: '',
documentation: ''
};
form ? form.reset() : null;
}
}
```

Comment: I see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720585/angular-form-resetting-with-ajax-callbacks

Which appears to be doing a similar thing but I do not know what should be passed in $scope

Comment: share the code of `DataRulesComponent`

Comment: @SunilSingh added to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### Issue

The issue is with keyword `this` used in following snippet.

```
newRule(form: NgForm) {
   this.rule = {
   ruleName: '',
   sqlQuery: '',
   description: '',
   frequency: '',
   emailAddressList: '',
   documentation: ''
}
```

You are defining the function `newRule` in `DataRulesComponent` and invoking this function in `DataRulesService` due to which context (`this`) is changed. When you invoke `newRule` function in `DataRulesService`, `this` will refer to `DataRulesService` not `DataRulesComponent` where you don't have `rule` variable. That why you are getting `undefined` error.

> ### Fix

The main objective of this `newRule` function is to `reset` the `value` of `rule` and `form` object. So lets implement the same in different way by creating new function `reset` in `Rule` class.

#### Step 1

```
class Rule{

   public reset(rule) {
       rule.ruleName =  '';
       rule.sqlQuery ='';
       rule.description = '';
       rule.frequency = '';
       rule.emailAddressList = '';
       rule.documentation = '';
    }
}
```

#### Step 2

Since you are already passing the `rule` no need to additional parameter `newRule`

Change

```
this.dataRulesService.createRuleRequest(this.rule, form, this.newRule);
```

to

```
this.dataRulesService.createRuleRequest(this.rule, form);
```

#### Step 3

The last would be in `createRuleRequest` function of `DataRulesService`. Just remove the last parameter

```
createRuleRequest(rule, form){
  ...
  rule.reset(rule); //it will reset rule.
  form.reset(); // reset the form
  ..
  //Above code will replace the function newRule(); 

}
```

> Note : I had written the code in `stackoverflow editor` directly so there could be `typo` and `syntactical` error. Please correct yourself.

Comment: Thank you, Sunil. This is exactly what I was looking for and is well-written and easy to understand.

Comment: After implementing this change I am getting an error:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ruleName' of undefined`

Comment: Updated the answer. I hope it will fix your problem.

Comment: Hi Sunil - This did not resolve my issue. I think there is a problem with the way I am instantiating the rule - do I need a constructor in the model?

Comment: print the value of `rule` inside `public reset(rule)` function and check if it undefined.

Comment: The app is erroring out before it gets to that point. I think the point where `rule` is undefined is in the html document. 

If I comment out the div for "ruleName" in the .html it moves on to telling me the next field is undefined (`cannot read property 'sqlQuery' of undefined`)

So it seems rule is undefined in my references to it in html.

Comment: Resolved. Seems my syntax in component.ts was the cause: 

`public rule: Rule;` had to be `public rule = new Rule;`

Comment: Excellent ! Glad to hear that you had figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using Angular's Reactive Forms. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms. This makes the `component.ts` file the single source of truth for the form instead of the template. You can do something like this:

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private service: RuleService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      rule: '',
      someOtherControl: null,
      andAnother: ''
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.service.createRuleRequest(this.myForm.value);
    this.myForm.reset();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mitch. This is good advice but I can't devote the time to the refactor.